# Building QuickFIX/J Distribution 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT error

Tags: quickfixj

I`m trying to execute the following mvn cmd after cloning the [project](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj):

mvn clean package -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DskipTests -PskipBundlePlugin

and i get a Build failure while building Building QuickFIX/J Distribution project:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------< org.quickfixj:quickfixj-distribution >----------------
[INFO] Building QuickFIX/J Distribution 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.quickfixj:quickfixj-codegenerator:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.quickfixj:quickfixj-dictgenerator:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.quickfixj:quickfixj-core:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.quickfixj:quickfixj-all:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.quickfixj:quickfixj-examples-banzai:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.quickfixj:quickfixj-examples-executor:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.quickfixj:quickfixj-examples-ordermatch:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-all:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fix50sp2:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fix50sp1:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fixt11:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fix50:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fix44:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fix43:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fix42:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fix41:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fix40:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.407 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-10T06:59:07-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project quickfixj-distribution: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.quickfixj:quickfixj-distribution:pom:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.quickfixj:quickfixj-codegenerator:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.quickfixj:quickfixj-dictgenerator:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.quickfixj:quickfixj-core:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.quickfixj:quickfixj-all:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.quickfixj:quickfixj-examples-banzai:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.quickfixj:quickfixj-examples-executor:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.quickfixj:quickfixj-examples-ordermatch:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-all:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fix50sp2:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fix50sp1:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fixt11:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fix50:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fix44:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fix43:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fix42:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fix41:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.quickfixj:quickfixj-messages-fix40:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.quickfixj:quickfixj-codegenerator:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

Has anyone have some ideas why am i getting this error ?!
I`m using Apache Maven 3.8.1.

Thank you.

Comment: What about the excess slash after `PskipBundlePlugin`? Did you try using `install` instead of `clean package`?

Comment: The last slash was a typo. I didn`t tried clean install, let me try now. I changed the version of quickfixj-distribution to 2.3.1 in pom.xml and it "worked" but I faced another error: "os=windows and the assembly descriptor contains a *nix-specific root-relative-reference"

Comment: Hmm could you please open a bug for this on https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/issues/new/choose

Comment: sure. Just let me try to reproduce the errors again to avoid creating a desnecessary ticket